# Why does this little program occupy 80% storage in my ESP32? any solutions?

Tags: esp32, memory

```cpp
#include "BluetoothSerial.h"
 
#if !defined(CONFIG_BT_ENABLED) || !defined(CONFIG_BLUEDROID_ENABLED)
#error Bluetooth is not enabled! Please run `make menuconfig` to and enable it
#endif
 
BluetoothSerial SerialBT;
 
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  SerialBT.begin("ESP32test"); //Bluetooth device name
  Serial.println("The device started, now you can pair it with bluetooth!");
}
void loop() { 
  for(int i=1; i<10000; i++){
    SerialBT.print("this is the sample number: "); SerialBT.println(i);
    delay(1);
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: If you look at the BluetoothSerial documentation, how much memory does it require? Not sure about that library specifically but Bluetooth is pretty complicated so it's probably going to need some RAM.

Comment: that's storage, not memory. an empty sketch takes up like 75%...

Comment: What optimization options were used with which compiler?

Answer (score 2):

Bluetooth is a complicated protocol. I've tested this with ESP-IDF rather than Arduino, and I believe the binary increased by about 300KB after enabling Bluetooth! It has some dependencies, and by just enabling that, you are adding those too. The same goes with Wi-Fi, printf() libraries, etc.

When using Arduino, most of these are enabled by default. Even if you don't reference them, some of these still end up in the binary. It's not easy to make a tool like Arduino that takes care of all the library management automatically. The cost of this would be inefficient binary size and RAM handling.

But, after that, it's mainly your application. My firmware for an empty main was around 900 KB. Going from 900 KB firmware to 1 MB firmware takes a lot of code! I used an ESP32-WROOM-32D with 4 MB of flash. I used the default partition table with 1.5 MB for SPIFFS and two partitions for OTA. I had a Webserver for webpages on the module, TinyGSM for SIM800, MQTT, RTC for DS3231, Neopixel library for LED, RadioHead for LoRa, Modbus RTU, etc. and ended up with less than 1.2 MB for firmware. At that point, the RAM space was not enough, and I couldn't add anything else.

Comment: Then it will be better to use Arduino NANO along with HC-05/06/08 instead using this useless item (ESP32) for BLE applications!!

Comment: Well, it depends. If you are making a cheap product, it's better to go with ESP32. Although with an empty main file, you end up with a big firmware, when you start adding your code, it does not change that much. A simple ESP32 comes with at least 1 MB flash. The ESP32-WROOM-32D comes with 4 MB of flash. Still a very good space for your program. I'll update the answer with a project I did. I ended up with less than 1.2 MB for firmware.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience Saadat... Kindly share more info about programming ESP32.. Welcome

Answer (score 0):

[image: Huge App Partition]

Understood that, third party BT chips like HC-08 will carry the code required to run BT protocol in their own memory hence the main microcontroller need not to carry/execute that code. Anyways, selecting Huge App from partition scheme has increased the storage space to 3MB & hence the program occupied space reduced from 80% to 33%